# Multi columns using union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I would like to create 2 columns of data out of a single union query of 2 tables with same field. I have 2 tables with "Utilizations" field in each table.

I tried the following query but I got an error.



    `select Utilizations as "Utilizations A", Utilizations as "Utilizations B" from 
    (select Utilizations as A, 0 as B from TableA 
    union all
    select 0 as A, Utilizations as B from TableB)`

Comment: Please share the full error text.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to alias your subquery, and second of all, you needed to refer to your columns in your outer query as A and B, not utilitizations:

```
select  A as "Utilizations A", 
        B as "Utilizations B" 
from 
  (select  Utilizations as A, 
           0 as B 
   from TableA 
   union all 
   select 0 as A, 
          Utilizations as B 
   from TableB
  )AS t
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer to this one. How about if I wanted to display non-zero values from the above. The reason why I put a zero in the query was because I needed 2 columns of data in the query. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide in your original question an example of what you want the output to look like?  That would help.